# Delete row with relationships and sub relationship, including images laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, models, relationships

I have 3 tables

```
Client
-----------
|id|client|
-----------
|1 |client|
-----------

Items
---------------------
|id|client_id|item  |
---------------------
|1 |   1     |item 1|
---------------------
|2 |   1     |item 2|
---------------------
Images
----------------------
|id|item_id|  image  |
----------------------
|1 |  1    |image.jpg|
----------------------
|2 |  1    |image.jpg|
----------------------
|3 |  2    |image.jpg|
----------------------
|4 |  2    |image.jpg|
----------------------
```

As you can see, table `client` can have many `items`, and table `items` can have many `images`. when a `client` will be delete, the `items` and the `images` of those `items` should be deleted to.

I tried to do something like this, but with no result.

```
$client->items()->images()->delete();
```

I also tried to make the full call but that only delete the client, like

```
$client->with(array('items' => function($items){
   $items->with('images');
}))->delete()
```

Its there a way to delete the client, the items of that client and the images of those items in a single transaction?

in adition i have read about `Model events` but honestly i do not understand it, i read i could use the next code, in what model do i put it? and what should i delete inside the `deleting` function

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function() {
       //what go in here?
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your database's foreign key to delete on cascade.

> $table->foreign('item_id')->references('id')->on('items')->onDelete('cascade');

That way you only have to delete the parent model.